# Would like to customize the UI, we currently use custom policies and custom HTML pages

Tags: html, azure-ad-b2c

Problem Statement:
Currently we are using AD B2C Reset Password Flow for User Registration and Forgot Password in our
application using custom policies and custom html templates. We are also applying custom CSS and
JavaScript. We want to simplify user registration process using AD B2C custom policies

Actual Requirement:
We would like to simply the flow for better user experience as below
Step1: We want to hide the Continue Button
[CustomUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VoM8.png)

[CustomUI-otpVerification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qusFL.png)

We would want to completely skip this page.
[CustomUI-otpVerified](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94QQS.png)

1. We would like to show user initial text that describes password requirements as below
   “Password requires at least 8 characters. Password must contain three of the following: At least
   1 upper case, 1 lower case, 1 number and 1 special character”.
2. We would also like to have all the errors display at one place instead of multiple places.

Limitations:

1. We tried applying custom JavaScript and CSS injected in our custom html template to achieve
   for the things mentioned above. But had no success.
   a. Some controls were common across multiple steps which were causing problems in
   different edge cases during development when applying some custom JavaScript.
   b. Since most of the main controls and form request were not in control in AD B2C, we
   were unable to do certain actions like programmatic click etc.,
2. We thought of updating AD B2C custom policies to achieve mentioned above. But we have not
   found any documentation about them.
   Preferred Solution:
3. Ideal solution we would be expecting is to update the AD B2C custom policies to achieve the
   desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

To Remove the continue button See the self asserted technical profile reference
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/self-asserted-technical-profile#metadata

Configure the setting.showContinueButton metadata item to false.
For the custom email verification templates [you can use sendgrid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-email-sendgrid)

1. You can user Password predicate validations in the custom policy to
   show the password field requirements

   Please refer this document for how to apply the [password predicate
   validations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/password-complexity?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#prerequisites)
2. To show all the validation messages at one place like the validation summary You have to [enable Javascript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/javascript-samples#prerequisites) for your policies and use [custom page content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-ui-customization#custom-page-content-walkthrough).

Recommended: Add a validation summary div before the api div (where B2C renders its content):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Product Brand Name</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="validationSummary"></div>
    <div id="api"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And display your validation summary using [vanilla javascript](https://www.codementor.io/@robertwozniak/form-validation-system-in-vanilla-javascript-oldy425jc) or [jQuery](https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/q23) results.

Comment: The "custom page content" link is broken. Where was it mean to go to?